# Function byte encode same input and have different responses

Tags: python, python-3.x, encode

How is this possible?  I'm using python3.

```
a= b"\xfc\x48\x83\xe4\xf0\xe8"
b= "\xfc\x48\x83\xe4\xf0\xe8"
if (a == b.encode('ascii',errors='replace')):
      print ("Winner")

print (a)
b'\xfcH\x83\xe4\xf0\xe8'
print (b)
üHäðè
```

I've tried different type of errors but nothing. If I don't put any error, it pop ups an error that It says `codec can't encode character '\xfc' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`. I have read the manual on [the official manual](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type) but I can't find any good answer.

I would like to know how to convert (force) B to be as A. Same print, same ouput.

**EDIT: I found the solution**. I wanted to convert from hex string to bytes. Finally what I did was to replace "\x" from the string. This leaves the string with HEX characters. Then I used the bytes function bytes.fromhex().

```
b = b.replace("\\x", "")
b = bytes.fromhex(b)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? `b.encode("ascii")` means take the ascii string and encode it to binary. But your ascii string isnt valid, just like it wouldn't be ascii if it contained chinese characters, emoji etc.

Comment: To convert Unicode characters in byte range (up to 255) to bytes, use encoding "latin-1".

Comment: I'm trying to convert (Force) string to byte object without adding anything. I'm having a program that returns a byte object as a string. I would like to declare this string returned as a byte object, same as I do with the A variable (But I can't make it).

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation you linked:

> Encodings don’t have to handle every possible Unicode character, and most encodings don’t. For example, Python’s default encoding is the ‘ascii’ encoding. The rules for converting a Unicode string into the ASCII encoding are simple; for each code point:
>
> If the code point is < 128, each byte is the same as the value of the code point.
>
> If the code point is 128 or greater, the Unicode string can’t be represented in this encoding. (Python raises a UnicodeEncodeError exception in this case.)

It looks like the first code point `\xfc > 128` which means you cannot represent it in `ascii` encoding.